# angular 10 : my request is not send after subscribe from observable in http request in interceptor

Tags: angular, interceptor

I want intercept all "delete" http and had a confirm dialog before.
If user click on "yes" a request is send else nothing append.

My interceptor look like :

```
@Injectable()
export class DeleteInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.method == 'DELETE') {
            this.dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteComponent).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
                if (result) {
                    return next.handle(req); // don't send
                }
            });
        }else{
            return next.handle(req); // work correctly
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Eva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add custom header
     if (req.method == 'DELETE') {
            console.log(req)

            return this.dialog.open(ExampleDialogComponent).afterClosed().pipe(
              filter(res => res),
              switchMap(res =>                      next.handle(req) // don't send
)

            )
                
        }else{
            return next.handle(req); // work correctly
        }
  }
}
```

This should solve it.
You need to return an observable in the end.